# Is it correct to use 'being' after a noun?

Tags: grammaticality, present-participles, being

I found the following sentence in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English (5th Edition):

- You can’t expect them to sit still for that long, children **being**
  what they are.

For me it sounds weirdly and ungrammatically because it seems that the noun 'children' leaves with no verb. I wish to use 'being' in the following way:

- **Being** what they are, children can't sit for that long.

Or:

- When children are **being** fidgety, they can't sit for that long.

Is this correct use of 'being' in the first example? If this is correct use, what I miss?

Comment: The original sentence is perfectly fine and idiomatic. Your first paraphrase of it is also reasonable and apt. The final paraphrase however, won't work: *children being what they are* means restlessness is a *fundamental, intrinsic characteristic of children*. Thus you can't say "*when children are*" without changing the meaning, because the original "*children being*" means this *isn't* a one-time, temporary, or accidental situation. They're never not going to be fidgetty. The "*when*" will never end. Children "are" restless (according to the original phrasing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  It's an [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction).